# Looking to learn how a Custom Field can change a value in the functions.php of a wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I have added a bit of code to my wordpress functions.php page, and it works as I wanted it.

It replaces where it says "abcd" with "1234"

However, what I would like to do would be able to replace abcd with a specific custom field. So abcd on each page, can be changed to something different, depending on the custom field value.

I was wondering, what would I need to change the 1234 in my code below to, if for example, my custom fields key is called cftest. Or is there any extra line of code that I should add?

Any help you can offer me would be hugely appreciated.

```
function replace_text($text) {
    $text = str_replace('abcd', '1234', $text);
    $text = str_replace('efgh', '5678', $text);
    return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the slug name of the custom field.

Also, if you roll your mouse over the custom field name in your Wordpress Admin, look at bottom of screen to see the tag_ID number.  This number may represent the value of what is in the custom field.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks yivi for posting the link.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your help.
By looking at your link, I found out how to solve my problem.

I changed the code above, to this and it worked perfectly

```
function replace_text($text) {

global $post;

$cftest = get_post_meta($post->ID, "cftest", true);

    $text = str_replace('abcd', '1234', $text);
    $text = str_replace('efgh', $cftest, $text);
    return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
```